# Prevent div from moving while the browser is in windowed mode

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am kind of new to CSS/HTML, and im trying to make a very simple and fast website for my company. I have successfully managed to create a website that i thought would meet the requirements they gave me. Please note that I was told not to use alot of time making this website.

The problem I have, is that the divs melt together when i put the site in windowed mode in the browser. What im trying to do is to make the site stay the same, and that the user will have to scroll around if the user is using windowed mode in the browser. I do not know if this make any sense to anyone, but I was hoping that someone could offer me an advice on how to do this.

I have tried many things, but none of them have worked. So my best guess is that something is wrong with my old school HTML code. :p

This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <style>

body {
  background-image: url("https://optimalassistanse.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/klepp-240x300.png"), url(https://orglogo.difi.no/api/logo/250/859223672), url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/56fc08f17c65e4e90c66db4c/5a4be277652dea72c86da007/5a95f84553450a754a4c5de8/1519778436009/Gjesdal.png?format=1500w), url(http://www.kommunenokkelen.no/listKommuner-portlet/img/kom_logo_middels/l1119.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right 1000px top -0%, right 1300px top -0%, right 400px top -0%, right 700px top -0%;
  background-size: 120px 120px; 
  }
div.wrapper {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:960px;
}
button.klepp {
position: absolute;
top: 10%;
right: 1000px;
top: 12%;
} 
button.time {
position: absolute;
top: 10%;
right: 1300px;
top: 12%;
} 
button.ha {
position: absolute;
top: 10%;
right: 712px;
top: 12%;
}
button.gjesdal {
position: absolute;
top: 10%;
right: 400px;
top: 12%;
}
div.felles {
    position: absolute;
    right: 400px;
    width: 40%;
    top: 150px;
}
div.felles2 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 150px;
    width: 40%;
    top: 90px;
}
div.test3 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 400px;
    width: 40%;
    top: 30%;
}
</style>
        <title>Ansatte i IT avdelingane</title>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:#edeef0c2;">
    <div div class="wrapper"> 
    <div>
            <button onclick="toogle_visibility('KleppKommune');" button class="klepp">Klepp kommune</button>
    </div>
    <div>
            <button onclick="toogle_visibility2('TimeKommune');" button class="time">Time kommune</button> 
    </div>
    <div>
            <button onclick="toogle_visibility3('HaKommune');" button class="ha">Hå kommune</button> 
    </div>
    <div>
            <button onclick="toogle_visibility4('GjesdalKommune');" button class="gjesdal">Gjesdal kommune</button> 
    </div>
    <div id="info" style="display:block" div class="felles">
        <br>
        <h1><font size="5">Velkommen</font></h1>
        <br>
        Her vil du finne informasjon om alle IT-ansatte i Jærkommunane. Klikk på et kommunenavn for å se informasjon om deres IT-ansatte. 
    </div>
    <div id="KleppKommune" style="display:none" div class="felles">
            <h1><font size="5">Ansatte i IT avdelingen hos Klepp kommune:</font></h1>
            <div>
            <b><font size= "4">Anja Kleppe Lyngra:</font></b>
            <br>
            <img src= "https://scontent-arn2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/13015473_10156851190915125_3361015358110699460_n.jpg?oh=f9bdc5e67c8621e0aed442ac12b9f24a&oe=5AFFA8D7" border="0" alt "Bilde av Anja" width="150" height="150">
            <br>
            <b><font size= "4"></font>Stilling:</b> Digitaliseringssjef
            <br>
            <b><font size= "4"></font>Erfaringer:</b> Digitalisering
            <br>
            <br>
            <b><font size= "4">Arve Aleksandersen:</font></b>
            <br>
            <img src="https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/AAMABADGAAwAAQAAAAAAAAqXAAAAJDRhZGY2Y2ZhLTFhODQtNDMxMi1hN2JkLTdjMDNkZjIxZjYzZA.jpg" border="0" alt="Bilde av Arve" width= "150" height="150">
            <br>
            <b>Stilling:</b> IT-Konsulent
            <br>
            <b>Erfaringer:</b> Office 365, Azure, 
            <br>
            integrasjon, scripting og automasjon, 
            <br>
            Windows Server, Exchange
            <br>
            <br>
            <b><font size= "4">Bjørn Haukås:</b>
            <br>
            <img src="C:\Users\eke10847\Pictures\bjorn.png" border="0" alt="Bilde av Bjørn" width= "150" height="150">
            <br>
            <b>Stilling:</b> IT-konsulent
            <br>
            <b>Erfaringer:</b> SQL
            <br>
            <br>
            <b><font size= "4">Øystein Lund:</font></b>
            <br>
            <img src="C:\Users\eke10847\Pictures\oystein.png" border="0" alt="Bilde av Øystein" width= "150" height="150">
            <br>
            <b>Stilling:</b> IT-konsulent
            <br>
            <b>Erfaringer:</b> Print
            </div>
            <div div class="felles2">
            <b><font size="4">Even Løland Kestilæ:</font></b>
            <br>
            <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/1zv5rms.png" border="0" alt="Bilde av Even" width= "150" height="150">
            <br>
            <b>Stilling:</b> Lærling
            <br>
            <b>Erfaringer:</b> Programmering, Office365, telefoni, brukerstøtte, MDM, Exchange
            <br>
            <br>
            <b><font size= "4">Johan Foss:</font></b>
            <br>
            <img src="C:\Users\eke10847\Pictures\johan.png" alt="Bilde av Johan" border="0" width="150" height="150">
            <br>
            <b>Stilling:</b> IT-Konsulent
            <br>
            <b>Erfaringer:</b> Telefoni
            <br>
            <br>
            <b><font size= "4">Lars Sunde:</font></b>
            <br>
            <img src= "C:\Users\eke10847\Pictures\lars.png" border="0" alt="Bilde av Lars" width="150" height="150">
            <br>
            <b>Stilling:</b> IT-driftssjef
            <br>
            <b>Erfaringer:</b> SQL, VmWare
            <br>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div id="TimeKommune" style="display:none" div class="felles">
            <h1><font size="5">Ansatte i IT avdelingen hos Time kommune:</font></h1>
            <p>
            <div>
            <b><font size= "4">Espen Kverneland:</font></b>
            <br>
            <img src= "C:\Users\eke10847\Pictures\uten navn.png" border="0" alt "Bilde av Espen" width="150" height="150">
            <br>
            <b>Stilling:</b> IT-sjef
            <br>
            <b>Erfaringer:</b> sjef
            <br>
            <br>
            <b><font size= "4">Kirsti Sveinsvoll:</font></b>
            <br>
            <img src="C:\Users\eke10847\Pictures\kirsti time.png" border="0" alt="Bilde av Kirsti" width= "150" height="150">
            <br>
            <b>Stilling:</b> IT-Konsulent
            <br>
            <b>Erfaringer:</b> MDM, ipad, Windows AS
            <br>
            VmWare, FEIDE, O365, Aruba
            <br>
            HP procurve, HP IMC, brukerstøtte. 
            <br>
            Er en del av IT avdelingen i kommunen, 
            <br>
            men jobber primært mot Oppvekst/Skole. 
            <br>
            <br>
            <b><font size= "4">Bjørn Haukås:</b>
            <br>
            <br>
            </div>
            <div div class="felles2">
            <b><font size="4">Torstein Tunheim Olsen:</font></b>
            <br>
            <img src="https://scontent-arn2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/p110x80/14671221_1480918125258692_7272885452219638259_n.jpg?oh=049f4c8bd93eca0ff768ac00dcdab30c&oe=5B44449C" border="0" alt="Bilde av Torstein" width= "150" height="150">
            <br>
            <b>Stilling:</b> Lærling
            <br>
            <br>
            <b><font size= "4">Johan Foss:</font></b>
            <br>
            <img src="https://scontent-arn2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/47494_426861588439_5443919_n.jpg?oh=713f88b3328dcb6dedf98af639697c8b&oe=5B11D51F" border="0" width="150" height="150">
            <br>
            <b>Stilling:</b> IT-Konsulent
            <br>
            <b>Erfaringer:</b> Telefoni
            <br>
            <br>
            <b><font size= "4">Lars Sunde:</font></b>
            <br>
            <img src= "https://scontent-arn2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/c0.0.370.370/p370x247/13615488_10210032582439140_4021367635855021644_n.jpg?oh=0152b2750f7b3c3962c00b3281e4b686&oe=5B439C65" border="0" alt="Bidle av Lars" width="150" height="150">
            <br>
            <br>
            <b><font size= "4">Øystein Lund:</font></b></p>
            <img src= "http://www.hjemit.net/lundweb/images-albums/oystalbum/oyst_ler.jpg" border= "0" alt="Bilde av Øystein" width="150" height="150">
            </div>
    </div>
    <div id="HaKommune" style="display:none" div class="felles">
            <h1><font size="5">Ansatte i IT avdelingen hos Hå kommune:</font></h1>
            <p>
            <div>
            <b><font size= "4">Anja Kleppe Lyngra:</font></b>
            <br>
            <img src= "https://scontent-arn2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/13015473_10156851190915125_3361015358110699460_n.jpg?oh=f9bdc5e67c8621e0aed442ac12b9f24a&oe=5AFFA8D7" border="0" alt "Bilde av Anja" width="150" height="150">
            <br>
            <b>Stilling:</b> Digitaliseringssjef
            <br>
            <b>Erfaringer:</b> Digitalisering
            <br>
            <br>
            <b><font size= "4">Arve Aleksandersen:</font></b>
            <br>
            <img src="https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/AAMABADGAAwAAQAAAAAAAAqXAAAAJDRhZGY2Y2ZhLTFhODQtNDMxMi1hN2JkLTdjMDNkZjIxZjYzZA.jpg" border="0" alt="Bilde av Arve" width= "150" height="150">
            <br>
            <b>Stilling:</b> IT-Konsulent
            <br>
            <b>Erfaringer:</b> Programmering, Office365, 
            <br>
            HyperV, SQL
            <br>
            <br>
            <b><font size= "4">Bjørn Haukås:</b>
            <br>
            <br>
            </div>
            <div div class="felles2">
            <b><font size="4">Even Løland Kestilæ:</font></b>
            <br>
            <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/1zv5rms.png" border="0" alt="Bilde av Even" width= "150" height="170">
            <br>
            <b>Stilling:</b> Lærling
            <br>
            <br>
            <b><font size= "4">Johan Foss:</font></b>
            <br>
            <img src="https://scontent-arn2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/47494_426861588439_5443919_n.jpg?oh=713f88b3328dcb6dedf98af639697c8b&oe=5B11D51F" border="0" width="150" height="150">
            <br>
            <b>Stilling:</b> IT-Konsulent
            <br>
            <b>Erfaringer:</b> Telefoni
            <br>
            <br>
            <b><font size= "4">Lars Sunde:</font></b>
            <br>
            <img src= "https://scontent-arn2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/c0.0.370.370/p370x247/13615488_10210032582439140_4021367635855021644_n.jpg?oh=0152b2750f7b3c3962c00b3281e4b686&oe=5B439C65" border="0" alt="Bidle av Lars" width="150" height="150">
            <br>
            <br>
            <b><font size= "4">Øystein Lund:</font></b></p>
            <img src= "http://www.hjemit.net/lundweb/images-albums/oystalbum/oyst_ler.jpg" border= "0" alt="Bilde av Øystein" width="150" height="150">
            </div>
    </div>
    <div id="GjesdalKommune" style="display:none" div class="felles">
            <h1><font size="5">Ansatte i IT avdelingen hos Gjesdal kommune:</font></h1>
            <p>
            <div>
            <b><font size= "4">Anja Kleppe Lyngra:</font></b>
            <br>
            <img src= "https://scontent-arn2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/13015473_10156851190915125_3361015358110699460_n.jpg?oh=f9bdc5e67c8621e0aed442ac12b9f24a&oe=5AFFA8D7" border="0" alt "Bilde av Anja" width="150" height="150">
            <br>
            <b>Stilling:</b> Digitaliseringssjef
            <br>
            <b>Erfaringer:</b> Digitalisering
            <br>
            <br>
            <b><font size= "4">Arve Aleksandersen:</font></b>
            <br>
            <img src="https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/AAMABADGAAwAAQAAAAAAAAqXAAAAJDRhZGY2Y2ZhLTFhODQtNDMxMi1hN2JkLTdjMDNkZjIxZjYzZA.jpg" border="0" alt="Bilde av Arve" width= "150" height="150">
            <br>
            <b>Stilling:</b> IT-Konsulent
            <br>
            <b>Erfaringer:</b> Programmering, Office365, 
            <br>
            HyperV, SQL
            <br>
            <br>
            <b><font size= "4">Bjørn Haukås:</b>
            <br>
            <br>
            </div>
            <div div class="felles2">
            <b><font size="4">Even Løland Kestilæ:</font></b>
            <br>
            <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/1zv5rms.png" border="0" alt="Bilde av Even" width= "150" height="170">
            <br>
            <b>Stilling:</b> Lærling
            <br>
            <br>
            <b><font size= "4">Johan Foss:</font></b>
            <br>
            <img src="https://scontent-arn2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/47494_426861588439_5443919_n.jpg?oh=713f88b3328dcb6dedf98af639697c8b&oe=5B11D51F" border="0" width="150" height="150">
            <br>
            <b>Stilling:</b> IT-Konsulent
            <br>
            <b>Erfaringer:</b> Telefoni
            <br>
            <br>
            <b><font size= "4">Lars Sunde:</font></b>
            <br>
            <img src= "https://scontent-arn2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/c0.0.370.370/p370x247/13615488_10210032582439140_4021367635855021644_n.jpg?oh=0152b2750f7b3c3962c00b3281e4b686&oe=5B439C65" border="0" alt="Bidle av Lars" width="150" height="150">
            <br>
            <br>
            <b><font size= "4">Øystein Lund:</font></b></p>
            <img src= "https://scontent-arn2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/c0.0.370.370/p370x247/13615488_10210032582439140_4021367635855021644_n.jpg?oh=0152b2750f7b3c3962c00b3281e4b686&oe=5B439C65" border="0" alt="Bidle av Lars" width="150" height="150">
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
                function toogle_visibility(KleppKommune) {
                    let x = document.getElementById("KleppKommune");
                    if (x.style.display === "none") {
                        x.style.display = "block";
                    } else {
                        window.alert("Klepp kommune er allerede åpen!")
                    }
                    x = document.getElementById("TimeKommune");
                    if (x.style.display === "block") {
                    x.style.display = "none";
                    } 
                    x = document.getElementById("HaKommune");
                    if (x.style.display === "block") {
                    x.style.display = "none";
                    } 
                    x = document.getElementById("GjesdalKommune");
                    if (x.style.display === "block") {
                    x.style.display = "none";
                    } 
                    x = document.getElementById("info");
                    if (x.style.display === "block") {
                    x.style.display = "none";
                    }
                  }
    </script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        function toogle_visibility2(TimeKommune) {
            let x = document.getElementById("TimeKommune");
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                        window.alert("Time kommune er allerede åpen!")
                    }
            x = document.getElementById("KleppKommune");
            if (x.style.display === "block") {
            x.style.display = "none";
            }
            x = document.getElementById("HaKommune");
            if (x.style.display === "block") {
             x.style.display = "none";
            } 
            x = document.getElementById("GjesdalKommune");
            if (x.style.display === "block") {
            x.style.display = "none";
            } 
            x = document.getElementById("info");
            if (x.style.display === "block") {
            x.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
                function toogle_visibility3(HaKommune) {
                    let x = document.getElementById("HaKommune");
                    if (x.style.display === "none") {
                        x.style.display = "block";
                    } else {
                        window.alert("Hå kommune er allerede åpen!")
                    }
                    x = document.getElementById("TimeKommune");
                    if (x.style.display === "block") {
                    x.style.display = "none";
                    } 
                    x = document.getElementById("KleppKommune");
                    if (x.style.display === "block") {
                    x.style.display = "none";
                    } 
                    x = document.getElementById("GjesdalKommune");
                    if (x.style.display === "block") {
                    x.style.display = "none";
                    } 
                    x = document.getElementById("info");
                    if (x.style.display === "block") {
                    x.style.display = "none";
                    }
                  }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
                function toogle_visibility4(GjesdalKommune) {
                    let x = document.getElementById("GjesdalKommune");
                    if (x.style.display === "none") {
                        x.style.display = "block";
                    } else {
                        window.alert("Gjesdal kommune er allerede åpen!")
                    }
                    x = document.getElementById("TimeKommune");
                    if (x.style.display === "block") {
                    x.style.display = "none";
                    } 
                    x = document.getElementById("KleppKommune");
                    if (x.style.display === "block") {
                    x.style.display = "none";
                    } 
                    x = document.getElementById("HaKommune");
                    if (x.style.display === "block") {
                    x.style.display = "none";
                    } 
                    x = document.getElementById("info");
                    if (x.style.display === "block") {
                    x.style.display = "none";
                    }
                  }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: so much absolute xD - check out `fixed` value for `position` attribute

Comment: positioning you code with absolute, is the reason why it's looking this way. Even if you were told not to spend a lot of time on it, you will need to spend some on learning how to position elements on the website. What I would suggest is read about flexbox which is relativly easy and very good way to position elements on the website

Comment: Wow. So many things going wrong :) . I suggest you check out flexbox and make your website responsive. There are tons of info on the net about responsive design. It won't take you long...it's pretty straight forward. Some of the problems :  using too many absolute positioned elements, using deprecated HTML tags ( font,border etc. ) use css styles instead. The javascript it's spaghetti . There are many ways to open/close when clicking on buttons ( check accordion/tabs ) . These are some of the problems. I am sorry to say but your entire code has to be reconsidered and re-written. Good luck !

Comment: it's pretty hard (if not impossible) to get a perfectly displayed website with the differences in browsers and operating systems (and the corresponding sizes that the windows may be).  I mention that because it is easy to waste time trying to make something perfect, when layout sometimes needs to be just "good enough".  Also, you may have to push back on whomever assigned this to you.  If they want their site done fast -- they either need to hire someone or give you the time to do it right.

Comment: I'm in agreement in dropping the `position: absolute` that'll just force things to stack where you don't want them to. Flexbox is the new hotness -- I don't know if it's easier than declaring height + width followed by maybe `float` the elements right or left.

Comment: Thanks for the fast help! I tried out the fixed instead of absolute and the divs did not melt together anymore, so thanks for that! But the problem now is that it is no scrolling so some content can't be showed. Do any of you have a tip on how to fix that?

Comment: Im sorry, i havn't been clear enough on the purpose of this website. Its only going to be an internal website with ONLY text and image on it. The purpose of the website is that an employee can go into the website, and click a button and read some information text. The website only need to work in Teams and Google Chrome. It is not supposed to be a professional or good looking website. It is only for showing information. The reason he assigned this for me was so that i could learn some simple HTML and CSS

Comment: (without using alot of time on it, as im going to learn HTML and CSS more advanced on my free time).